# React native re-architecture release version

Tags: react-native

In various articles, one can read about ReactNative re-architecture which eliminates the bridge in favour of JavaScript Interface (JSI), introduces Fabric as a replacement of the UI manager etc. In the same articles, authors refer to the architecture with the bridge as the "old one" but I can't find any information in which version the re-architecture was introduced (if at all).

I would be pleased if somebody could tell me in which version these changes were introduced or confirm that it's not released yet.

Comment: It's not out yet. AFAIK the only related development that's in the wild so far is Hermes, the new JS engine on Android